TikZ syntax issue, extra right-brace in \foreach command
In this extract from code at https://www.aprendematematicas.org.mx/helicoide-generalizado-codigo-fuente-latex/#comment-36265, the following command gives a syntax error of possible Runaway argument:
line 45: 0\fi\ \else \expandafter \pgfmth@function@@@@process \expandafter {\pgfmath@@operand \ETC

namely:
paragraph ended before \tikz@math@collecttosemicolon was complete.

The lines are:
\foreach \t in {\ti,\tj,...,\tf}{
    \draw[cyan,very thin,opacity=0.35] plot[domain=\pi:\pf,smooth,variable=\p] ({Equis(\t,\p)},{Ye(\t,\p)},{Zeta(\t,\p)});
}

What's wrong?
(When those two lines, and another such pair following them, are commented out, the TikZ document compiles without error.)
The complete code, with what seem to be extraneous parts removed, is:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{math} 

\begin{document} 
% 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120} 
% 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale= 1.5] 
    \tikzmath{function equis(\t){return 0.0;} ;} 
    \tikzmath{function ye(\t){return \t ;} ;} 
    \tikzmath{function zeta(\t){return 0.50 * (\t - 1.0)^2 ;} ;} 
    \tikzmath{function Equis(\t , \p){return equis(\t) * cos(\p r) - ye(\t) * sin(\p r);} ;} 
    \tikzmath{function Ye(\t , \p){return equis(\t) * sin(\p r) + ye(\t) * cos(\p r);} ;} 
    \tikzmath{function Zeta(\t , \p){return zeta(\t) + \m * \p ;} ;} 
%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{250} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ti}{0.0} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tf}{2.0} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pi}{0.0} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pf}{6.0 * pi} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tj}{\ti + (\tf - \ti) / \n} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pj}{\pi + (\pf - \pi) / \n} 
    \foreach  \t in {\ti , \tj ,..., \tf}{
        \draw[cyan, very thin, opacity=0.35] plot[domain= \pi : \pf ,smooth ,variable= \p] ({Equis(\t , \p)} ,{Ye(\t , \p)} ,{Zeta(\t , \p)});
    } 
\end{tikzpicture} 
% 
\end{document}

My apology
The TikZ code on the cited page does compile just fine.
No disparagement to the author of the code was intended.
I just didn't realize what had happened when I asked Google translate to convert the page into English, then copied the code from the translated version: Google translate inserted spurious spaces all over the place after and before delimiters and after backslashes. My attempting to fix that just compounded the problem. So...
WARNING Do not try to compile TikZ code that has been touched by Google Translate!

I think we covered it in our comments on the post ;). And I probably should have asked you if you planned to leave another comment before writing mine. It was only that I didn't like the only comment on it to be a claim it didn't work, as I thought it might well deter people from trying.

The original code works fine and its author is merely a(nother) victim of Google Translate.
Moral of the story: don't trust Google (again).
In removing 'what seem to be extraneous parts' of the code, you have made one slip and overlooked one crucial change made by Google Translate.

You have eliminated the declaration of \m. This is obviously fatal, but I assume you'd have realised the slip if the code had proceeded this far.
Google has altered the syntax of the \tikzmath commands erroneously. In particular, it has introduced spaces between the final brace delimiting the function definition and the following semicolon. Apparently, pgf does not like this and expects the semicolon to follow immediately.

Hence,
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{math} 
% Côd gwreiddiol:
% File name: generalized-helicoid.tex
% Author: Efraín Soto Apolinar
% Date of creation: June, 26th 2024.
% Apodaca, N.L., Mexico.
% https://www.aprendematematicas.org.mx/author/efrain-soto-apolinar/instructing-courses/
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale= 1.5] 
  \tikzmath{function equis(\t){return 0.0;};} 
  \tikzmath{function ye(\t){return \t ;};} 
  \tikzmath{function zeta(\t){return 0.50 * (\t - 1.0)^2 ;};} 
  \tikzmath{function Equis(\t , \p){return equis(\t) * cos(\p r) - ye(\t) * sin(\p r);};} 
  \tikzmath{function Ye(\t , \p){return equis(\t) * sin(\p r) + ye(\t) * cos(\p r);};} 
  \tikzmath{function Zeta(\t , \p){return zeta(\t) + \m * \p ;};} 
  %
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{0.25}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{250} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ti}{0.0} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tf}{2.0} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pi}{0.0} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pf}{6.0 * pi} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tj}{\ti + (\tf - \ti) / \n} 
  \foreach  \t in {\ti , \tj ,..., \tf}{
    \draw[cyan, very thin, opacity=0.35] plot[domain= \pi : \pf ,smooth ,variable= \p] ({Equis(\t , \p)} ,{Ye(\t , \p)} ,{Zeta(\t , \p)});
  } 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}


Because pgf/tikz often tolerates variable syntax, it is easy to think the details don't matter, especially because the manual doesn't usually highlight cases where intolerance is to be expected. In general, most things will work ... until they don't.
For instance, note that the following is fine,
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{math} 
% Côd gwreiddiol:
% File name: generalized-helicoid.tex
% Author: Efraín Soto Apolinar
% Date of creation: June, 26th 2024.
% Apodaca, N.L., Mexico.
% https://www.aprendematematicas.org.mx/author/efrain-soto-apolinar/instructing-courses/
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale= 1.5] 
  \tikzmath{
    function equis(\t){return 0.0;};
    function ye(\t){return \t ;};
    function zeta(\t){return 0.50 * (\t - 1.0)^2 ;};
    function Equis(\t , \p){return equis(\t) * cos(\p r) - ye(\t) * sin(\p r);};
    function Ye(\t , \p){return equis(\t) * sin(\p r) + ye(\t) * cos(\p r);};
    function Zeta(\t , \p){return zeta(\t) + \m * \p ;};
  } 
  %
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{0.25}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{250} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ti}{0.0} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tf}{2.0} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pi}{0.0} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pf}{6.0 * pi} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tj}{\ti + (\tf - \ti) / \n}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pj}{\pi + (\pf - \pi) / \n}
  \foreach  \t in {\ti , \tj ,..., \tf}{
    \draw[cyan, very thin, opacity=0.35] plot[domain= \pi : \pf ,smooth ,variable= \p] ({Equis(\t , \p)} ,{Ye(\t , \p)} ,{Zeta(\t , \p)});
  }
  \foreach \p in {\pi,\pj,...,\pf}{
    \draw[cyan,very thin,opacity=0.35] plot[domain=\ti:\tf,smooth,variable=\t] ({Equis(\t,\p)},{Ye(\t,\p)},{Zeta(\t,\p)});
  }
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}

and produces the entire helicoid.


(1) Sorry, my omitting the definition of \m from the sample code and allegedly "complete" code was inadvertent, and was in the code I actually tried to compile. (2) Before I copied the code, I used Google translate to translate the web page into English; the tranlated version inserted extraneous spaces all over the place, e.g., between the initial \\ and the rest of tokens, and before and after delimiters; and I tried to fix that.

@murray Ah. Another thing you shouldn't trust to Google ;). That wouldn't have occurred to me. To be honest, I didn't see much on the page worth translating, as most of it was ads, so I just copied the code. As I said, I'm sure you would have figured out the \m because that error was obvious. Just the first one wasn't.
